# Pass java script parameters from html page loaded in Iframe inside Chrome extension to this extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to access java script parameters in html page when loaded in iframe. 
i can not access these parameters using document.getelemetbyId("frame-id").content.variablename because there is a deference between chrome extension protocol and iframe or html page protocol (protocol doesn't match)

Q: Is there a method of accessing javascript parameters inside an iframe from a Chrome content script extension? If yes, what permissions and other manifest options should I specify? Thanks.

note: i tried to use messages communication to send message from html page that loaded inside iframe to the chrome extension  but it's so complicated and i don't find a clear tutorial